# Android Studio passes an error to Unity

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine

Before using this method in the Eclipse to pass the value of Unity, but now on the Android Studio on the error, disable this method on everything is normal

```
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class U3dActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("APP", "message", "Test");

    }
 }
```

Error:[image]

Comment: I don't know if you can call UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage from onCreate. Try calling it from another method and see if the crash still happens.

Comment: I tried, as long as the implementation of the method to UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage reported more than the error, this method is disabled on the normal, Unity5.5, AndroidStudio2.1.2, sdk5.0